# Mouseenter fired multiple times in Firefox after moving node to another place in DOM

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, mouseevent

I have a problem with `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` unexpected behavior in Firefox. The thing I need to do is:

1. Move the node to another place in DOM after mouse enter has been registered on it
2. Then move it back to original place after mouse leave has been registerd on it

**The problem is that after inserting the node into another place, `mouseenter` fires like crazy and `mouseleave` doesn't fire at all.**

Here's a **[pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXweYQ)** illustrating that. You should inspect console output to see how many times mouseenter is fired. It might seem nonsensical in the pen, but in my app it isn't. I'm adding a zoom to the image on hover. One of it's ancestor's has `overflow: hidden` (which I cannot fight with CSS) and hides the enlarged portion of the image. So after the image is zoomed I need to move it into some other place in DOM (while making sure that it stays in the same place on the screen), then move it back in place when zoom is over (mouse leaves the image).

**Question**

Can someone explain to me what happens here? And how to fight it to achieve the regular `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` behavior (fired only once).

Comment: `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` fire once for me as they should. I am using Chrome 43. What environment you are testing it on?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 34 on Debian amd64.

Answer (score 1):

First: Your variables `outer1` and `outer2` are the same.

Second, if you are changing the element of node it will trigger the `mouseleave` because the cursor is no longer on top of the element..

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```js
var inner1 = document.getElementById("inner1");
var inner2 = document.getElementById("inner2");
var outer1 = document.getElementById("outer1");
var outer2 = document.getElementById("outer2");
var moved = false;

inner2.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
  if (moved) {
    zoomOut();
  } else {
    zoom();
  }
});

function zoom() {
  console.log("mouseenter");
  outer2.appendChild(inner1);
  moved = true;
}

function zoomOut() {
  console.log("mouseenter 2");
  outer1.appendChild(inner1);
  moved = false;
}
```

```css
#outer1,
#outer2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
#outer1 {
  background-color: green;
}
#outer2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
}
#inner2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer1">
  <div id="inner1">
    <div id="inner2">Hover me</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="outer2">
</div>
```

As you can see I only listen to the `mouseenter` event because the `mouseleave` will always be triggered after you append the element. I added a flag: `moved` to figure out where the div is.

Comment: `appendChild()` doesn't trigger `mouseleave` on my Firefox 34. That's for sure, because I register handler for `mouseleave` and it's never invoked, not even after `appendChild()`.

Comment: And in my app it's different than in the pen because the **cursor stays at the element all of the time** - the element is moved in DOM, but using absolute positioning I make sure that it stays at the same place on the screen. But the real problem here seems to be how `mouseenter` gets registered like crazy after `appendChild` is invoked.

Comment: Of course it will be. Because if it triggers the `mouseleave` you append the element back to the to the first box and the `mouseenter` will trigger again, its an endless loop.

Comment: Then if your app is different give us an example that will in fact help you.

Comment: I thought this example shows the same problems. I can re-write it so that it's more similar to my app, but first take a look at my console output from current pen: http://i.imgur.com/1TLcGjQ.png. Is yours similar?

Comment: The pen you provided shows the same symptoms in my browser - mouseenter gets fired hundreds of times, while mouseleave doesn't fire at all (no alert displayed). Is it some browser related problem then?

Comment: You are right. In firefox it doesn't trigger. On chrome it does. Anyways my answer works on both of them.

Comment: Removing `mouseenter` handler after registering first `mouseenter`, then registering it again only on `mouseleave` solves the problem on Firefox. Still it looks like a Firefox bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem using D3 and a force-directed graph.

Each node has a `mouseenter` handler that calls `this.parentNode.appendChild()` to bring the element to the top.  It's the only way I know of to rearrange SVG elements.

This works fine in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox, it causes the looping `mouseenter` behavior.  No `mouseleave` event is ever fired, either.

Best fix I have right now is to only call `appendChild()` when the node is not the topmost (`node.nextSibling !== null`)